# K8s VconfigMap class object of python lib processing in robot framework

Tags: python, kubernetes, robotframework

K8s VconfigMap class object of python lib processing in robot framework

**Testcase that am trying to do**

1. get the config map details for a particular config map using python
2. do some changes in the object in robot framework
3. call the patch config map function by passing the changed object

***Python Lib:***

```
from kubernetes import client, config, utils

def get_config_map(self, configmap_name, namespace):
        try:
            api = client.CoreV1Api()
            resp = api.read_namespaced_config_map(name= configmap_name, namespace= namespace)  #this returns V1ConfigMap class object
            return(resp)      
        except Exception as e:
            raise

def patch_config_map(self, configmap_name, namespace, body):
        try:
            api = client.CoreV1Api()
            resp = api.patch_namespaced_config_map(name= configmap_name, namespace= namespace, body= body)
        except Exception as e:
            raise
```

***Robot framework***

```
*** Test Cases ***

patch config map
    [Documentation]    Patch the config map
    [tags]    performance    test-weekly     prom
    ${configmap_details}=   get config map      configmap_name=${perf_configmap_name}    namespace=${namespace}
    Log     ${configmap_details}['data']
    #Here I need to manipulate the returned class object
    #am getting error like
```

> Variable '${configmap_details}' is V1ConfigMap, which is not
> subscriptable, and thus accessing item 'data' from it is not possible.
> To use '[data]' as a literal value, it needs to be escaped like
> '[data]'

[https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/ae7b5ddd219fe09b6ed0be715dcca3377a029584/kubernetes/docs/CoreV1Api.md#read_namespaced_config_map](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/ae7b5ddd0219fe09b6ed0be715dcca3377a029584/kubernetes/docs/CoreV1Api.md#read_namespaced_config_map)

https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/ae7b5ddd219fe09b6ed0be715dcca3377a029584/kubernetes/docs/V1ConfigMap.md

So need clarity on whether possible to manipulate the class object type in robot framework

Comment: V1ConfigMap object is not a dictionary, so you cannot use ['data']. The object V1ConfigMap has an attribute 'data', so you can use it as object.data. Eg: ${configmap_details}.data

Comment: I have tried that as well. But its printing like this 

{'api_version': ....}.data

its just printing like string.. in robot framework